# How to check if a byte from a byte array contains 0 using C?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I have a `byte array` of `strings`. How can I check if a byte in that array contains 0? For example:

```
char byte_arr[5] = "abc00";
```

The last two bytes of the above array contains 0. How can I detect that in `c`?

Comment: You don't have a byte array of strings. You have invalid code.

Comment: @Cheatah Could you correct me in that case?

Comment: `char byte_arr[5] = "abc00";` would be valid.

Comment: What's wrong with comparing the elements of the array with the value you're looking for?

Comment: Please refer to any form of documentation about string functions. You can't really miss it.

Comment: Are you looking for the numeric value 0 or for the character value `'0'`?

Comment: @IanAbbott: "*... would be valid.*" but still is not defining a C-string, as the '0'-terminator is missing.

Comment: How do you check if this array contains the value zero? `int arr [5] = {1,2,0,3,4};`. Write the code for that, then try to do the same for a char array.

Answer (score 1):

Simple algorithm to follow

```
count_zero = 0
for each element a, in byte_array
    check if a is '0'
        count_zero++
```

Comment: *You can use ASCII value `48` too to compare instead of `'0'`.*  **Why?!?!**  `'0'` will work everywhere.  If you hardcode `48`, the code is needlessly limited to ASCII.

Comment: @AndrewHenle did not think about that, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Even if we make this code compile (assuming that `uint8` is defined somewhere)

```
uint8 byte_arr[5] = "abc00";
```

then no bytes in this array (except the 5th one) has value zero. Last two hold value of the character `'0'` which depends of the character encoding used.

To check if a particular element of the array holds some value you need to compare it with that value

```
if(byte_arr[4] == '0') printf("Success!!!!\n");
else printf("Failure!!!!\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters your character array does not contain a string.

```
char byte_arr[5] = "abc00";
```

So to determine whether the character '0' is present in the array you have to traverse it elements using its size.

In this case you can use a loop as for example while loop

```
size_t i = 0;
char c = '0';

while ( i < 5 && byte_arr[i] != c ) i++;

if ( i != 5 ) printf( "The character %c is present at position %zu\n, c, i );
```

If you need to determine positions of all elements that contain the character `'0'` or count them then you can use for example a for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 5 };
    char byte_arr[N] = "abc00";
    char c = '0';
    
    size_t count = 0;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( byte_arr[i] == c )
        {
            ++count;
            printf( "At the position %zu there is the character '%c'\n", i, c );
        }
    }
    
    printf( "There are %zu elements in the array that contains '%c'.\n", count, c );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
At the position 3 there is the character '0'
At the position 4 there is the character '0'
There are 2 elements in the array that contains '0'.
```

If you would declare the array for example like

```
char byte_arr[] = "abc00";
```

then the array will conmtain a string. In this case you can use the standard string function `strchr` that checks whether a given character is present in a string. For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char byte_arr[] = "abc00";
char c = '0';

char *p = strchr( byte_arr, c );

if ( p != NULL ) printf( "The character %c is present at position %zu\n, c, ( size_t )( p - byte_arr ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a standard function for this, in `string.h`, if the task is just to determine whether or not there are any:

```
if ( memchr(byte_arr, '0', sizeof byte_arr) )
    printf("There was a zero.\n");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop the array until you reach the end or find the desired char:

```
int main(void) {
    char byte_arr[5] = "abc00";
    for (int i =0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        if(byte_arr[i]=='0'){
            printf("Found!!");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```